# How can I add intel Fortran compiler after installed intel oneAPI and visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran, intel-oneapi

I installed visual studio 2022 Community. Also, I installed Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit and Intel® oneAPI HPC Toolkit. However, I do not know how to configure fortran compiler into visual studio so I can make Fortran project. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. It would be good to see the exact current state of your installation.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you did not select the "Desktop development with C++" workload when installing Visual Studio. The oneAPI HPC Toolkit install should have given you a warning about this. For more details, see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-for-use-with-intel-compilers.html

For help with the Intel Fortran compiler, I recommend asking in Intel's support forum at https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/bd-p/fortran-compiler

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually installed  "Desktop development with C++" workload when I was installing MSVS. I just deleted everything and re-installed everything and it worked. Thanks for your help